# ring endomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can anyone offer some help?

Let $R$ be an unital ring $(1\ne 0)$. Recall than with $R^{\,\text{op}}$ we denote the opposite ring which is a ring as usual, only it haw a reverse multiplication $\left( x\square y=yx \right)$.

We denote $R$ as a left $R$-module with ${}_{R}R$. (equivalently for right R-module)

Prove that

$\operatorname{End}_{R}({}_{R}R)\cong R^{\,\text{op}}$,

$\operatorname{End}_{R}({}_{R}R)=R$.

Hint: if $f$ is an endomorphism of ${}_{R}R$, then $f(r)=f(1\cdot r)=f(1)r$

Thank you for your time

Comment: I assume you typo’d $R_R$ in the second one, because otherwise it is wrong.  The second one is, essentially, answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/895087/29335). The first one follows the same way, just by using definitions.

Comment: [Also answers the question completely](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2185417/29335) although I won't risk duplicating.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The morphism $\;\operatorname{End}_R({}_RR)\longrightarrow R^{\,\text{op}}$ maps an endomorphism $f$ to $\varphi(f)=f(1)$.

You have to check that

- $\varphi(f+g)= \varphi(f)+\varphi(g)$ for all endomorphisms $f,g$;
- $\varphi(f\circ g)=\varphi(f)\varphi(g)$ in $R^{\,\text{opp}}$;
- $\varphi(\mathrm{id})=1_{R^{\mkern1.5mu\text{opp}}}$.